# Microsoft Graph: Getting "Deleted" change notification for sent message

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, change-notification

I created a messages subscription to Microsoft graph api to track changes.

When I send an email, I get many created, updated, and deleted change notifications for the item. It is unclear what the "final" state should be when these notifications arrive in no particular order.

I can process the created and updated notifications by storing and checking changeKeys and checking the lastModifiedDateTime.

But I am finding it difficult to process the "deleted" change notifications because they have no changeKey or lastModifiedDateTime, and I am unsure how to distinguish this unnecessary "deleted" notification (which I want to ignore) from a real "deleted" notification generated by deleting a mail item (which I would want to ingest).

Is it expected to get a deleted notification when sending mail? If so, how do I process it to ensure I end up in the correct state? If not, any ideas why this may be happening?

Comment: Are you checking the source folder of the item that generated the change? eg if its coming form the drafts folder the you can probably safely ignore the notification as part of the compose process of particular clients also using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-immutable-id may help if you not using it currently. Also with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks-with-resource-data?tabs=csharp you can include the messageFlags to check the state of a Message or the last verb executed tetc

Comment: Thanks Glen, I am using immutableIds, and the change comes from the Sent Items folder, unfortunately. It honestly feels like a bug.